Оптимизация вложенных циклов для работы с большими наборами данных
Мне нужно обработать многомерный массив, содержащий более 10 миллионов элементов. Вложенные циклы неэффективны при увеличении размера данных. Вот пример кода, который я использую:
data = [[[randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(1000)]

def process(value):
    # Пример обработки данных
    return value * 2

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        for k in range(len(data[i][j])):
            data[i][j][k] = process(data[i][j][k])
print("Время выполнения:", time.time() - start_time)

Примерный объем данных составляет 10 миллионов элементов, распределенных в трехмерном массиве (1000 x 100 x 100).

Интересны библиотеки и подходы для оптимизации обработки (фокусная задача)
Отдельно интересна параллельная обработка (побочная задача)


в сторону векторизации смотрели? numpy/numba?

@strawdog про гпу речь? Неа, не смотрел

да пока просто про векторизацию речь. gpu - это уже "вторая серия".

И numpy и numba такую ерунду за доли секунды думаю обработают.

Список представляет собой набор математически не связанных элементов, поэтому подобные операции приходится выполнять перебором. Вам надо использовать библиотеку numpy, которая представит Ваш набор данных как вектор и Вы сможете производить подобные вычисления сразу со всем объектом. Ваша задача будет выглядеть так:
from random import randint
import numpy as np

data = [[[randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(1000)]

np_data = np.array(data) # превращаем список в массив numpy
np_data *= 2 # здесь функция, которую надо применить к каждому элементу

Это будет очень быстро.
UPT
Проведем замеры. Операцию с вектором померяем двумя способами. В случае если у Вас есть возможность изначально хранить данные в векторе, померяем только операцию умножения. Если нет - померяем и конвертацию в вектор и умножение.
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import time

data = [[[randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(1000)]
np_data = np.array(data)

start_time = time.time()
np_data *= 2
print("Время выполнения умножения вектора:", time.time() - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
np_data = np.array(data)
np_data *= 2
print("Время выполнения преобразования в вектор и умножения вектора:", time.time() - start_time)

def process(value):
    # Пример обработки данных
    return value * 2

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        for k in range(len(data[i][j])):
            data[i][j][k] = process(data[i][j][k])
print("Время выполнения умножения перебором:", time.time() - start_time)

Результаты:
Время выполнения умножения вектора: 0.005906820297241211
Время выполнения преобразования в вектор и умножения вектора: 0.5156631469726562
Время выполнения умножения перебором: 2.2284791469573975

UPD2
Решил, чисто для изучения, украсть ответ CrazyElf и замерить на моем железе, для сравнения. То есть меряем вместе с генерацией вектора методами numpy.
start_time = time.time()
np_data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 100, 100))
np_data *= 2
print("Время выполнения генерации и умножения вектора:", time.time() - start_time)

Вот:
Время выполнения генерации и умножения вектора: 0.10832500457763672


Как понять: что такое "очень" и на сколько очень? Можно сравнение на вашей архитектуре?

@hedgehogues изменил ответ

1/10 секунды в Google Colab и генерация таких данных и обработка:
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 100, 100))
data *= 2


Можно сравнение в облаке?
